# Windows Update behavior with Update KB971092

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update

Last night, my company performed a windows update for the following three updates [KB972260](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=972260), [KB971090](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971090) and [KB971092](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971092/).  I installed all three updates on my workstation and rebooted.

When I logged back into my workstation, the windows update icon appeared stating I still need KB971032.  I ran windows update again to install the update and after it completed the installation it appeared again.

I have gone through the process four times, even restarted my machine twice, and the icon still is appearing.

I am running Windows XP Pro with Service Pack 3.

What is the best way to troubleshoot this issue?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Kevin Kuphal, he provided the following workaround to resolve the Windows Update issue with KB971032:

[Workaround](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/Workaround.aspx?FeedbackID=478117)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try downloading the update manually

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=294de390-3c94-49fb-a014-9a38580e64cb

and installing it and see if that resolves the issue.  It also looks like this can occur if the C++ components are not installed

Comment: I downloaded the patch and tried to run the update manually and received the following statement:  "VC Libraries QFE patch does not apply or is blocked by another condition on your system."

Comment: Microsoft Connect offers a workaround : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/Workaround.aspx?FeedbackID=478117

Answer (score 2):

So far, 91 people have confirmed that they have had problems with VS90SP1-KB971092-x86.exe on MSConnect at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=478117 -

If you have had problems with this QFE, please go to the MSConnect and vote for this update to be clarified.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as Micheal.

I just unzipped (using 7zip) the package (downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=294de390-3c94-49fb-a014-9a38580e64cb thanks Kevins) and ran VS90SP1-KB971092-x86.msp.

This is based on the second link provided by Kevin 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/Workaround.aspx?FeedbackID=478117

Answer (score 0):

168 people have now confirmed that there is a problem with this fix if you did not install the C++ components. If you have this problem and have not yet voted at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=478117&wa=wsignin1.0, please do so.